# Is the idea of the 'Sadharana Shloka' present in scripture?

Tags: shloka, reference-request

There is an argument about the "Shuklambaradharam" shloka and who it praises: Ganesha or Vishnu?

When researching that, I stumbled onto [this blog post](https://www.wattpad.com/286190406-things-you-probably-dont-know-from-hindu-texts-the) which says that the debate Ganesha vs Vishnu debate is moot - this shloka, being a "Sadharana Shloka", can be used to pray to any deity.

**Is this concept of "Sadharana Shloka" present in scripture?**